# Selenium Python Authenticating browser login pupup dialog at a HTTPS website

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, web-scraping

Folks,

I am working on a scraping script which is running once a day where I need to re-authenticate my account.

First I have to login and then only I can see the page. Like normal page login and scrapping this won't work (read in articles and used the code below as suggested on most of the blogs and forumns) This still doesn't work.

It's an `https` website.

URL: https://www2.somewebsite.com/mypage.php

[image]
 [image]

Now I have this code:

```
def InitializeBrowser():
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.set_window_size(1120, 550)
    return browser

def CheckTest(request):
    browser = InitializeBrowser()
    data = browser.get("https://gitroix:Ju2R4kmb@www2.sfmx.org/camera.php")
    alert = browser.switch_to_alert()
    alert.accept()
    browser.close()
    return HttpResponse(data.contents)
```

However the above code doesn't fills in the data in popup box fields, not clicks on Login.

What would be the issue?

**EDIT 1:**

I did tried this from [How to Submit HTTP authentication with Selenium python-binding webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022116/how-to-submit-http-authentication-with-selenium-python-binding-webdriver)

But no success either.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('network.http.phishy-userpass-length', 255)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("https://username:password@somewebsite.com/")
```

Comment: provided image is not the `Firefox`, but `Safari` dialog box... how it actually looks like in your case?

Comment: @Andersson Just posting firefox image also. A moment.

Comment: got the same case and tried the same thing on normal http protocol with firefox. `browser.switch_to_alert` is not executed at all. The code got stuck at `browser.get`.

Comment: @DjangoAnonymous Are you able to resolve above problem? I have also facing the same issue and not able to resolve it. This code is not working in my case
driver.get("https://username:password@testwebsite.com/testpage.html")

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://username:password@testwebsite.com/testpage.html")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```