# Alert disappears before script can switch to it using Selenium + Python + Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a Python (3.6.6) script that uses Selenium (3.141.0) to open a URL in Chrome (ChromeDriver version 77.0.3865.40), navigate a series of menus, enter login details into a popup and login. Here's my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = 'https://some.url.com/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
action = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get(url)

button_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'button_1_text')]")
button_1.click()

button_2 = driver.find_element_by_id('button_2_text')
button_2 .click()

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('link_text')
action.move_to_element(link).perform()
link.click()

alert_obj = driver.switch_to.alert
```

If I perform this navigation manually, I get a prompt asking for a username and password, with two buttons to sign in or cancel. When Selenium does it, I see the prompt flash up, but then quickly disappear, so I get the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert
```

If I refresh the still open browser manually I can get the alert to appear, but if I script a refresh the prompt once again vanishes. I've tried putting a wait in for an alert to appear, as described in [Check if any alert exists using selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003003/check-if-any-alert-exists-using-selenium-with-python), but the wait just times out.

If I check the source code of the page that is left open once the alert has disappeared, I see this:

```
<!-- template name: form.autopost.template.html -->

<html>
    <head>
    <title>Submit Form</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="javascript:document.forms[0].submit()">
       <noscript>
            <p>
                <strong>Note:</strong> Since your browser does not support JavaScript, you must press the Resume button once to proceed.
            </p>
        </noscript>
        <form method="post" action="another_url.saml2">
                        <input type="hidden" name="SAMLRequest" value="really_long_token"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="token"/>
                        <noscript><input type="submit" value="Resume"/></noscript>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

So I tried explicitly enabling JavaScript with:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

This seems similar to [Selenium test - Firefox alert disappearing immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925815/selenium-test-firefox-alert-disappearing-immediately), but it looks like I can't recreate the solution using Chrome. I tried the following:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

But that made no difference either. Is there another way to prevent Selenium/Chrome from automatically closing the alert?

Here is a screenshot of the popup:

[image]

I have tried adding the following to the end of my script:

```
current_url = driver.current_url
parts = current_url.split('//')
login_url = parts[0] + '//{}:{}@'.format(username, password) + parts[1]
driver.get(login_url)
```

But this doesn't help. The login URL looks like this:

https://username:password@some_site/1S14/idp/G6tue/resume/idp/prp.ping?pfidpadapterid=idp.CG2LlmzHFUrah4EmDQ7jO_XTLGP&rememberChoice=true

Comment: what happens if you remove the code that handles the alert box? e.g. delete `alert_obj = driver.switch_to.alert`. does the login happen successfully? or you get error for unexpected alert?

Comment: Usually entering username and password does not happen in Alerts. Why do you expect an alert? Could it be possible this is another html element, and not alert box?

Comment: post the markup for the login form... (if there is any...)  If there is no markup, it could be a notification or an alert... It's worth mentioning that the default behavior for an unhandled prompt is to dismiss and notify... which means an exception would be thrown, so try/catch the last step to see if this happens.  Also see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57481723/is-there-a-change-in-the-handling-of-unhandled-alert-in-chromedriver-and-chrome

Comment: Without the switch to alert, the script ends successfully, no errors to catch. I assumed it was an alert, but that's likely my inexperience, it could be something else. I'll post a screenshot of the popup. With it active I'm unable to inspect the site with Chrome (right-click does nothing) - is there another way to check if it has markup?

Comment: Open the inspector... F12 in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a similar project for my firm, what you will have to do is browse to that URL using UI Automation (Lib:pyautogui) then input the username and password. After that you are free to do anything using Selenium.

Your code wont go beyond "driver.get(url)", it will be forever stuck there.

Answer (score 1):

If the prompt you get is browser login, then you can try setting the username and password like this:

```
driver.get("https://username:password@somewebsite.com/")
```

as described in this post [Selenium Python Authenticating browser login pupup dialog at a HTTPS website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356564/selenium-python-authenticating-browser-login-pupup-dialog-at-a-https-website)

But this IS NOT an ALERT, and that's why you can't handle it with `driver.switch_to.alert`, and you get the exception.

Comment: OK, I've tried this a few different ways with little success. Apologies I just realised I didn't mention in my question - this is a corporate intranet site. If I log in manually I have to give a domain with my username like `DOMAIN\username`. Following your suggestion with the domain in the username, I get blocked by my company's firewall, without the domain it makes no difference to the behaviour described in my question. I should note that my initial URL isn't the one with the login prompt, I navigate to that - is it possible to extract the current URL from a webdriver to start a new GET?

Comment: I've tried extracting the URL of the page with the login prompt, then using `driver.get('https://username:password@login_url')`, but that does the same thing as described in my last comment. I'll post the URL in my question. Also worth pointing out that if I login manually, I have to enter my credentials twice (I don't know why).