# How to submit HTTP authentication (Flask BASIC Auth) with Selenium to ChromeDriver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, flask, selenium-chromedriver

I am accessing a Flask app URL with [BASIC Auth](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/)

```
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def main():
    xvfb = Xvfb()

    xvfb.start()

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://user:password@192.168.178.55:7000/wow')

    xvfb.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Passing the *user* and *password* with the URL doesn't work

Any further pointers?

> I am pretty aware that there is at least a dozen posts that seems to deal with this same exact issue, although none actually resolve it while using the **ChromeDriver** with Flask BASIC Auth or are simply outdated.
>
> [Here for Firefox only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022116/how-to-submit-http-authentication-with-selenium-python-binding-webdriver) or [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672407/how-to-perform-basic-authentication-for-firefoxdriver-chromedriver-and-iedriver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved by adding a `/` at the end of the URL

```
driver.get('https://user:password@192.168.178.55:7000/wow/')
```